# Amadeus Safe Place API

Tags: api, amadeus

How I can get a list of place identifiers **{safety-rated-locationId}** for Safe Place API?

```
{api_url}/safety/safety-rated-locations/{safety-rated-locationId}
```

I don't see any helpful information on the [api documentation page](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/destination-content/api-doc/safe-place/api-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The first and the second endpoints allow you to retrieve a list of `safety-rated-locations` for a given location (by radius or by square).

For example:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/safety/safety-rated-locations?latitude=41.397158&longitude=2.160873&radius=2

```
{
        "type": "safety-rated-location",
        "id": "Q930402719",
        "self": {
            "type": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/safety/safety-rated-locations/Q930402719",
            "methods": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        "subType": "CITY",
        "name": "Barcelona",
        "geoCode": {
            "latitude": 41.385064,
            "longitude": 2.173404
        },
        "safetyScores": {
            "lgbtq": 39,
            "medical": 69,
            "overall": 45,
            "physicalHarm": 36,
            "politicalFreedom": 50,
            "theft": 44,
            "women": 34
        }
    }
```

Each of these `safety-rated-locations` contains an `id` (here `Q930402719`) that you can then use in the third endpoint to retrieve only this specific information:

> https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/safety/safety-rated-locations/Q930402719

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for something like a list of all cities and their IDs without searching by coordinates.

Comment: As of today, we do not offer a search by city name. You can retrieve the coordinates of a city and use the search for that city. You will then get the list of ids for this city.